# How can I make a Search String to search like an IN filter on an Array of Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

The filter on UI allows a user to search using the IN criterion. The search string will then become the property of the condition Object.
The search string will look like `"1234,5436,8765"` and then the `condition Object` will be like ```

```
condition: {
     field: "Id",
     operator: "in",
     value: "1234,5436,8765"
}
```

Now as this is going to be IN filter, so whar criterion should I use so as to make the value search like IN criterion from the `results Array`.

e.g. for a like filter, I will set my value property like this `%1234%` so as to search this in the results Array.

Comment: question is unclear !

Comment: Are you just asking how to create a comma-separated string of the values in your array? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear so try to edit it to make it clearer.

I made a huge assumption here in my answer (as it is not clear from the question):

You could do it with a switch statement and then your various filter methods for each case.

You could do it more robustly, but until the question is clearer, it doesn't make much sense to build this solution out.

```js
const myArrOfObs = [
    {Id: 1234, title: "some title 1", other: "some other val 1"},
    {Id: 2468, title: "some title 2", other: "some other val 2"},
    {Id: 8240, title: "some title 3", other: "some other val 3"},
    {Id: 9371, title: "some title 4", other: "some other val 4"},
    {Id: 5436, title: "some title 5", other: "some other val 5"},
    {Id: 8365, title: "some title 6", other: "some other val 6"},
    {Id: 8765, title: "some title 7", other: "some other val 7"},
    {Id: 3946, title: "some title 8", other: "some other val 8"}
];

const condition = {
     field: "Id",
     operator: "in",
     value: "1234,5436,8765"
};

function filterArr(arr, cond) {
  switch (cond.operator){
    case "in":
      const valueArr = cond.value.split(',');
      return arr.filter(item => valueArr.includes(item[cond.field].toString()));
    //case "like":
      //return arr.filter( ... );
    default:
      return null;  
  }    
}

const myFilteredArr = filterArr(myArrOfObs, condition);

console.log(myFilteredArr);
```